# Passing Textbox values from a Textbox to a different (not form.cs) Class

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

Still new to C# .NET so simple (with explanation) is preferred. :) I have a Windows form with a few textboxes. I want to be able to read in the contents of these textboxes,**in a separate file.**  I've seen articles (also here on stackoverflow) which cover similar problems, but don't work in my case. 
The data I want is to be found in textboxes in Form1.
Where I want this data to go is -> myOtherCS, where it will be used in a method (Savedoc).

In Form1.cs I have:

```
private myOtherCS allOtherMethods;
public static string myText= "";
public static string mytitle = "";

public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();            
    allOtherMethods = new myOtherCS();
}
/* I would like the myText to be filled with the contents of Textbox1
 *  and mytitle to be filled with contents of Textbox2. Ideally when the
 * Textboxes have been changed.  */

private void TextBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     myText = Textbox1.Text;
}

private void TextBox2_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     myTitle = Textbox2.Text;
}
```

In myOtherCS file I want to be able to use these values within a different method. So first probably "get" and "set"-ing them.
I've tried a lot of things but here is one.. to get the idea from.. I do know that you have to change things in both files, and have, but this is to get the idea.

```
public class GetTextBoxes
{
    private string title;
    private string text;

    public string Title
    {
        get { return title; }
        set { title = value; }
    }

    public string Text
    {
        get { return text; }
        set { text = value; }
    }
}

public void SaveDoc()
{ 
    GetTextBoxes.title;
    GetTextBoxes.text;
}
```

This is PSEUDOcode as of yet, to try to show what I want to do. I've tried many things, if someone knows how to do this, I would very much appreciate it! Thanks in advance

Comment: Is this other form a child form of this one, a parent form, a sibling form, or what?  What is the relationship between them?  That will define both how they can and should interact.  Using public static fields somewhere is almost certainly an inappropriate way to go about solving the problem.

Comment: Actually, it is not a form at all! That's why I can't solve this, hehe. I've seen alot of pages with forms exchanging info. But this is a class file (containing the main programming) whereas the form1.cs just has buttons and the UI. each of the buttons calls a function within the allOtherMethods.cs file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have said that your form is calling methods in another class when you click a button, and those other methods need to use the current value of your text boxes when performing their calculations.  The proper way to deal with that is to just have those other methods accept two string parameters and to pass the textbox's `Text` value when you call those methods.

Doing that will allow you to remove the text changed handlers and the public static fields.  It will ensure that the information isn't exposed to everything, when really only these two classes need to have access to it, and it will make your program easier to maintain going forward.

Comment: Actually it was not what I was trying to ask. I have edited.  No offense to the male population, but I'm female btw, so not "he"..

Comment: @SuusvdVen I see nothing in your edit to indicate that this isn't *exactly* the solution to your problem, and you've marked this as the answer, so I'm confused as to how this is not related to what you were trying to ask.

Comment: oh sorry.. no that was because you said my form is calling methods in another class, when actually the other class is calling values from the form.  Little technicality, but other way around.. that's what i meant.

Comment: I marked this as answer, because even through my unclear question, you gave the corrent answer ;)  In other words, creating the string parameters works.. and is simple too

Comment: @SuusvdVen Why is the other class "calling values from the form".  That probably shouldn't be happening, and it doesn't appear to be happening from what you've shown.  If it is, you should show the relevant section of code in which the other class is referencing the form.

Comment: it isn't in the question because I didn't know if that was allowable, and when I tried, I couldn't get the thing working. I can post my code but where? As it's answered basically. I would love to show the workings. umm.. holiday goes in right now, so i'll get back to ya

Comment: @SuusvdVen You can post it in exactly the same way you've posted all of the other code snippets in the question, you just omitted the important points, which is how the two classes are currently interacting on the button clicks.

Answer (score 1):

If you are storing the strings as public then all you have to do is say...

```
Form1 form=new Form1();
Console.out.write(form.myText);
```

if your strings are public there is no need to use getters and setters. Though i probably would keep them as static. These methods will update after every change so no extra method is required. You could also set your title objects to public they are type so what you did with the string can just be implemented again but with parts of your form.

```
public System.Windows.Forms.Button button1;
```

Comment: Actually I wanted to use the contents within another method. So I think it isn't as simple as that. I did just try making them public and then doing "form1.title" etc. but didn't work

Answer (score 1):

I think the best way is what you have done . having an public class to get and set values and share them between different windows forms is the idea I myself always use . You can also pass your values through form constructors but that is when you want to get a value only on form initialization ! so in your case I don't think It's a good idea . . . good luck

Comment: Yes! that's the problem I was having! I don't want it on form initialization. So where/how do I do this? Do you have an example of information within a form, and how you pass that to a "worker class".cs to play with?

Answer (score 1):

You may want to change your way of thinking, here some thoughts:

- Think of it more in terms of data models. What is your Form1 trying to represent conceptually? Based on that create your data model to support that need. By data model I mean just a simple Class(es) with getters/setters as you have defined in your question, you could call your class Document.

  public class Document
  {
      public string Title {get;set;}
      public string Text {get;set;
  }

  So instead of having your static fields in Form1:

  public static string myText= "";
  public static string mytitle = "";

  you could define a public property `public Document MyDocument {get;set;}`
  and initialize it in the Constructor.
- Then you could use Data Binding so you can bind your model (Document) to your Controls in Form1.
- Think of your interaction between Form1 and myOtherCS. How do you envision user's Workflow? Filling Form1 and then execute an action? go to another form, etc? Is myOtherCS just a Service that will process Form1 data?

Rather than helping you with your specific technical issue, i'd like to broaden your perspective and identify what you really want to do, then find the most appropriate technical solution to fulfill that requirement. Believe me, I've struggled a long time with WinForms but it is more important to have clear what you want to accomplish at a high-level.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the properties of allOtherMethods in the textchanged event handler.

Here is the code:

```
private void TextBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   allOtherMethods.Text = Textbox1.Text;
}
private void TextBox2_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   allOtherMethods.Title= Textbox2.Text;
}
```

And the code

```
public void saveText()
{ 
       GetTextBoxes.title;
       GetTextBoxes.text;
}
```

is meaningless. You can not declare a method outside a class.

c# is an OOP language. So the common concept here is that you should always try to set the properties or invoke a method of an instance in the event handler.

Comment: Yes, true, as I said it was to explain what I wanted. I actually want to "get the text boxes" (both of them) and use them among other code within the saveText()... which is again within the allOtherMethods.cs file.

Comment: @SuusvdVen So what I mean here is that you should move your 'Text' and 'Title' properties to the class 'myOtherCS'. Then you use the event handler mentioned above. So now you can get the two values inside the 'allOtherMethods' which has the 'SaveText()' method.

Comment: thanks. That idea seems to be working. and ofc it is simpler than a get/set. I don't know if it's taking an easy way out, and making the code less flexible, but it's good enough for me.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say that each your main form and the other form contain one textBox. What you could do is open the other form with `Show()`, passing in the main form as a parameter. Then, you could add an event handler for the text change. The sample below will update your `TextBox` on the other form, when the main form 's `TextBox` text is changed. Here is your main form:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    OtherForm otherForm;
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        otherForm = new OtherForm();
        otherForm.Show(this);
        textBox1.TextChanged += textBox1_TextChanged;
    }

    void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        otherForm.textBox1.Text = textBox1.Text;
    }
}
```

In the `OtherForm` designer, set `textBox1` `Modifiers` to `Public`, as shown below

[image]

**[EDIT]**

Here's a better approach based on [Servy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1159478/servy)'s suggestion.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    OtherForm otherForm;
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        otherForm = new OtherForm();
        otherForm.Show(this);
    }
}

//...

public partial class OtherForm : Form
{
    public OtherForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    string SomeMethod()
    {
        var parent = (Form1)this.Owner;
        return parent.textBox1.Text;
    }

    private void textBox1_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        textBox1.Text = SomeMethod();
    }
}
```

Comment: This entire paradigm is poor practice.  Forms shouldn't be exposing their child controls publicly, and child forms shouldn't know about their parent form or be holding references to them.  Beyond that, based on the OP's comments he's not trying to pass the info to a child form, so the entire answer isn't relevant to this question.

Comment: I also agree that this is a poor practice, but I've posted the answer in order to better demonstrate on a simple level how values from one form could be used to set object values in the other one. He said: _...I want to be able to read in the contents of these textboxes, in a separate file..._, so I guess he is trying to update variables based on the text change.

Comment: Why would you suggest something you know is poor practice?  You should be teaching him how to do it properly, rather than improperly.  He's not in a position to know better.  Doing it correctly is also not particularly hard.  In fact, doing it correctly is much easier.  See my answer.